# CrossDomain.xml issue Unity3D, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, unity-game-engine, web-deployment, wcf-security, unity-web-player

I'm in having a trouble ... I'm calling a service from my unity3D game, but it says no `crossdomain.xml` policy file found. for the time being I'm using LOCALHOST as `http://localhost:3537/Service1.svc/search?q=newquery` and I've place `crossdomain.xml` in the root folder of server i.e. I can get contents of that file by `http://localhost:3537/crossdomain.xml` file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

and when I call the service I use `InspectElement/Network` (in Chrome), here I can see request is send to `http://localhost:3537/crossdomain.xml` and response is received i.e. contents of xml file but still it says after response "**Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file found**". I've search a lot but nothing is going to work. I've read [Security Sandbox of the Webplayer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html)  but unable to find solution. I've added `Host URL` in `Edit/Project Setting/Editor` as `http://localhost:3537` then it work fine in unity3D, but if I build it and run ... Same ERROR ... kindly help me, I've less time as I've to submit my Project. This is my code

```
WWW url = new WWW("http://localhost:3537/Service1.svc/search?q=newquery");
yield return url;
if(url.error == null)
{
    str = "WWW Ok!: " + url.text;
} 
else {
    str = "WWW Error: " + url.error;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've overcome this issue, after a long struggle, by just saving the `crossdomain.xml` in ANSI (8 bits) encoding scheme which is similar to ASCII (7 bits), I've used notepad for this purpose. like following

[image]